# Can CVS repository commit command pass command line arguments to the files?

Tags: unix, tcl, cvs, tortoisecvs

Is there a way to pass command line arguments to the files present in the CVS repository.
Say, my CVS repository has a .tcl file which prints version number and date along with other processing. I don't want to hardcode the version number and date into that file. 
Whenever somebody modifies the file and checks it into CVS, can they add a tag for version number and date which will modify the tcl file accordingly?

Say I have test.tcl

```
puts "Version Number: **V1.2**
puts "Date: 05/05/10"
....
.....
```

If I modify the file and want to commit into CVS, 
saying 
`"cvs commit test.tcl v1.3 06/19/15"` or something like that

the test.tcl should get committed in CVS and it should be:

```
    puts "Version Number: **V1.3**
    puts "Date: 06/19/15"

......
......
```

Is there a way to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First hint: keyword substituion

If you just want version numbers or commit time - CVS has something that enraged Linus Torvalds so much he started to design `git`: it can change your files on commit. See for example $Id$ and others at [this MIT doc page](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/cvs_17.html).

Second hint: see [Running arbitrary scripts under CVS](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2003/06/05/scripts.html), the title says it all.